# No me reconoce require js

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy intentando editar un archivo json mediante js para ello encontre como hacerlo en el **siguiente enlace** https://es.quora.com/C%C3%B3mo-hago-un-archivo-JSON-con-JavaScript.

pero me dio el **siguiente error** Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at pruebas.mjs:1:12

**El código:**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Configurar elementos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="crear_elementos">Crear elementos</button>
        <button id="borrar">Borrar</button>

        <script type="module" src="pruebas.mjs"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*pruebas.mjs*

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
 
let objectToSave = {variable:'1',variable2:'2'} 
 
fs.writeFile('archivo.json', JSON.stringify(objectToSave),'utf8', (err) => { 
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('The file has been saved!'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente, de lado cliente, no existe ninguna libreria FS. El módulo FS solo existe de lado servidor usando Node.JS. Para utilizar FS de lado cliente deberás de usar librerias del estilo [Web-FS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-fs). Para ello deberás transpilar tu codigo con webpack o equivalentes. Igualmente, el post de Quora que has adjuntado, claramente especifica al inicio del post que para ejecutar su codigo necesitarás NodeJS